# 3 related tables to one

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to connect values from 3 related tables to one.
I have 3 tables:

table: U

```
╔════╦══════════════╦
║uid ║    name      ║
╠════╬══════════════╣
║  1 ║    admin     ║
║ 92 ║      a       ║ 
╚════╩══════════════╝
```

table: N

```
╔════╦══════════════╦
║uid ║     nid      ║
╠════╬══════════════╣
║  1 ║     152      ║
║ 92 ║     153      ║ 
╚════╩══════════════╝
```

table: R

```
╔════╦══════════════╦
║ id ║   user_id    ║
╠════╬══════════════╣
║152 ║     92       ║
║153 ║      1       ║ 
╚════╩══════════════╝
```

I would like to display

```
╔════╦══════════════╦════════╗
║ id ║     name1    ║ name2  ║
╠════╬══════════════╬════════╣
║152 ║     admin    ║    a   ║
║153 ║       a      ║  admin ║ 
╚════╩══════════════╩════════╝
```

I tried such SQL query

```
SELECT nid id, name name1, user_uid name2
FROM u u, n n, r r
WHERE u.uid = n.uid
AND n.nid = r.id
```

But it return in table name2 only values like 1,92. How to change those to admin, a

Comment: Tables `R` and `N` seems to be copies of each other with different column names. Perhaps improving your naming might make things clearer.

Comment: whats the relationship between the tables?

Comment: Tables N and R are different. Is it possible to connect all to have the result as I described?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, the `user_id` column in table R references the `uid` column in table U.

If so, you need a second reference to table U to provide `name2`.  I'd write it like this:

```
select n.nid, u1.name as name1, u2.name as name2
from u u1
  inner join n on u1.uid = n.uid
  inner join r on n.nid = r.id
  inner join u u2 on r.user_id = u2.uid
```

I've used table U twice - once to provide name1 and a second time to provide name2.

Comment: This is actually ANSI-standard SQL, this should work on _any_ RDBMS.